# Subroutines in PLC - does it decrease scan time?

Tags: plc

Does adding subroutines to a PLC program tend to decrease its scan time, or simply make it easier to T/S and program?

I came across an old exam question which asks what could be done to decrease the scan time of a PLC program.    The answers given were increasing clock speed, adding timer blocks, adding comparative blocks, and adding subroutines.

Personally, I don't see how any of these are a viable way to decrease scan time...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's multiple choice, then "increasing clock speed" will decrease the PLC scan time.

If the ladder logic (or whatever language) is the same between two processors, but one has a faster processor (i.e. increased clock speed), then the faster processor will run through a single logic scan faster than the slower processor.

Comment: I was tending to agree with this answer, but all the research I did points to a up-clocking as impractical - that's why I asked it here - thanks for your reply.!

Comment: They are correct.  The embedded microprocessor is rated at a specific clock speed, and a lot of firmware is written based on that specific clock speed.  However, if the actual PLC CPU comes in different flavors, say a low grade vs. a high grade, but the high grade has a faster processor, then that would be OK, since it was designed product (not just hacking the clock signal).

Comment: But realize that you typically do not need to be concerned about PLC scan time for a majority of applications, since it will be "fast enough".  Some PLCs have High Speed I/O modules that have their own processors for super-fast I/O, again, not requiring a super fast main logic CPU.  If you ever do need to optimize, realize that bottle necks are where you least suspect.  Profile your code and use Paretto Analysis to figure out exactly what those are and try to optimize those, BUT ONLY WHEN NEEDED.  Otherwise, you are wasting your engineering time reducing scan time from 4ms down to 3ms.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what the answer for your exam question says is that if you add timer blocks, comparative blocks and subroutines **controlled** by those elements (timers, comparative and many other PLC functions to control program flow), you run pieces of code selectively. With this scenario in my opinion you could considerably improve PLC scan time.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify - it was a multiple choice Q ! so only one of those was the correct answer !   Thanks for responding !

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on PLC or sometimes on Runtime. For instance, Codesys 2.3 does not support subroutines even if PLC has a good CPU. It supports parallel program launch through tasks, but those are not really run parallel.

So, there are a number of factors, to get the exact answer I need to know PLC manufacturer and a model.

But in general, the logic say, the more code you execute, the longer it takes to process one cycle. So more subroutines you add, the longer one cycle time is.